# Uncaught TypeError: Aa is not a function (Youtube APIs)

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I'm having problems with the integration of the player youtube: the error is "**Uncaught TypeError: Aa is not a function**", on line 24 of **www-widgetapi.js** from `http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfltoz0n9/www-widgetapi.js`.

How can I fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $myJ = jQuery.noConflict();

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '769',
      videoId: 't5bDtxuLc3Y',
      playerVars: { 'modestbranding': 1, 'showinfo': 0, 'autohide': 1, 'rel': 0, 'origin': 'http://www.testsite.com', 'wmode': 'opaque'},
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: did you define `onPlayerStateChange` and `onPlayerReady`?

Comment: Yes, i've declared that functions

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmm... widgetapi is part of your code? You are using some extension? Try to run your code in browser-private mode

Comment: Already tested in private mode, www-widgetapi.js is automatically downloaded from s.ytimg.com, as Youtube.

Comment: Check this sample https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started